# How to inherit Class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function is not working, It is not putting values in "input".

```
function example(id){
    this.code= function(){$('.'+id).val(id)}
    this.validate= function (){
        $('.'+id).keyup(function (e){
            if(e.keyCode==13) this.code();
        })
    }
}
```

**body**

```
<input type="text" class="test"/>
<input type="text" class="test1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test= new example('test')
    var test1= new example('test1')
    test.validate()
    test1.validate()
</script>
```

Comment: I think the functions inside "example" will get "undefined" in place of "id". You should store the id into some private var in the function example.

Comment: @MightyPork: no, the function in `this.code` will inherit the parent function's scope, and will have knowledge of the `id` var.

Comment: you are aware that your `validate()` function just registeres a `keyup` handler, and does not actually perform the validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keyup event handler will have a different "this". You can use bind to correct the problem

```
keyup(function (e){
if(e.keyCode==13) this.code();
}.bind(this))
```

When you bind to an event, the handler is called with the "this" keyword set to the object that fired the event, not the object that created the event.

Comment: One more thing. you bind 'this' to keyup event and inherit 'this' to its parent function. If my keyup function inside is another function and if I want to inherit 'this' to parent function then how to bind it

Comment: @amit - You could use a variable like the other answer by Petoj to save the "this" -- var self = this; -- and then use "self" inside of the other since the variable will be accessible up the scope chain.

Comment: @lastCoder: I use setTimeout method. It is filling value without pressing the enter key.   this.code= setTimeout(function(){$('.'+id).val(id)},20)

Comment: @LastCoder: It is working when I am putting setTimeout inside a function, what is the problem

Comment: @amit - setTimeout works differently than an event (like click or keyup) handler. The "this" inside a setTimeout function will be the global scope (window), although it will still have access to the parameter variable id. You would need to use bind again on the -- setTimeout(function(){...}.bind(this),123); --

Answer (score 1):

Well javascript is a bit hard to understand when it comes to this..

this article explains some of it http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html
But one way to solve it would be

```
function example(id){
    this.code= function(){$('.'+id).val(id)}
    var self = this;
    this.validate= function (){
        $('.'+id).keyup(function (e){
            if(e.keyCode==13) self.code();
        });
    }
}
```